# How to validate child component from parent component without clicking or touching in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a child component call app-account included a submit form with some input fields validattors like this

```
this.user = this.fb.group({
        usrname: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required])),
        password: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]))});
```

and in HTML template

```
<form [formGroup]="user" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Account" formControlName="usrname">
    <mat-error *ngIf="!!user.controls.usrname.errors?.required">{{usrrequire_msg}}
    </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password">
    <mat-error *ngIf="!!user.controls.password.errors?.required">
        {{pwrequire_qmsg}}
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="!!user.controls.password.hasError('minlength')">
        {{pwminimum_msg}}
    </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

I embedded this component like a child comp to a parent component HTML

```
<app-account></app-account>
```

and in the parent component i have a button to Submit

Layout is load fine but when i click submit button from parent component with any clicking or touching to child input field => Have not any error validate message is display?

How can i resolve it, thanks!

Comment: Did you import the child into the parent?

Comment: @Swoox yes, i have imported and the template of the child is successfully display in the parent, when i click or touch in child fields then click to other place (don't input anything) the required message is display perfect... But if I submit without any click or touch, no error message show!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [formControl].markAsTouch() with [formControl] is form control from children component... this method will make an action like the use touch or click into this field. Then the validation message is showing.